# Finding an object in an image

Tags: image, matlab

How do I find a license plate in an image?

I thought to look for the color of the plate, but I have a problem when there is another thing in the image in the same color.

Comment: Is there a way to make it check shapes or border colors (Since I don't know of any license plates that don't have a border)?

Comment: i didn't think to look for the borders, it's a nice idea. but how can i distinguish between other borders that the image contains?

Comment: Try using the search function: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=license+plate

Comment: I posted a working solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777677/determining-color-range-for-pixel-comparison/4778495#4778495

Answer (score 1):

In general you're going to be looking for some other features that make it obviously a license plate. Using some combination of [feature detectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28computer_vision%29) will probably help disambiguate this. There's already a lot of [literature on detecting license plates](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=license+plate+detector&oe=utf-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&hl=en&tab=ws).